# How can I break up a javascript string with a new line every five words?

Tags: javascript

I have an unusual request. Given a string like the following:

```
var a = "This is a sentance that has many words. I would like to split this to a few lines"
```

I need to insert a "\n" every fifth word. The string a can have any number of alphanumeric characters.

Can someone give me an idea how I could do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168644/splitting-a-string-by-an-array-of-words-in-javascript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
a.split(/((?:\w+ ){5})/g).filter(Boolean).join("\n");
/*
    This is a sentance that 
    has many words. 
    I would like to split 
    this to a few lines
*/
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very clean solution so I chose this one.

Comment: NB that Array.prototype.filter does not exists in IE 8 and below. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility for a polyfill if you need IE 8 support.

Comment: This does not work if the string contains non-word symbols like punctuation. To accomodate for that, use `q.split(/((?:\S+\s*){5})/g).filter(Boolean).join('\n');` (here `\S+\s*` matches a longest sequence of non-space symbols frollowed by whitespace)

Answer (score 4):

Idea first came to my mind

```
    var a = "This is a sentance that has many words. I would like to split this to a few lines";
a=a.split(" ");var str='';
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
if((i+1)%5==0)str+='\n';
str+=" "+a[i];}
alert(str);
```

Comment: Damnit! I was typing this and you posted it :) Have an upvote.

Comment: You need ((i+1)%5==0) otherwise it will already insert a \n after the first word.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string into several words and join them together while adding a "\n" every 5th word:

```
function insertLines (a) {
    var a_split = a.split(" ");
    var res = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < a_split.length; i++) {
        res += a_split[i] + " ";
        if ((i+1) % 5 === 0)
            res += "\n";
    }
    return res;
}

//call it like this
var new_txt = insertLines("This is a sentance that has many words. I would like to split this to a few lines");
```

Please consider that "\n" in html-code (for example in a "div" or "p" tag) will not be visible to the visitor of a website. In this case you would need to use "<br/>"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var a = "This is a sentance that has many words. I would like to split this to a few lines"
var b="";
var c=0;
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    b+=a[i];
    if(a[i]==" ") {
        c++;
        if(c==5) {
            b+="\n";
            c=0;
        }
    }
}
alert(b);
```

Comment: dude it will hang the browser if the string will too much long

Comment: It was not my idea. I provided just a possible solution. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. The strings are just small 5-25 words usually.